# Count properties of objects in list using java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

So let's suppose I have an `Arraylist` of the object `Animal`. That class of the object is like this:

```java
class Animal{
    String Name;//for example "Dog"
    String Color
}
```

What I want to do, is count how many different colors exist for each animal in the `ArrayList` and put them in a `Map<String,Integer>` where `String` is the Name and `Integer` is for the number of different colors.

For example if there are 4 black dogs and 1 white the equivalent put to the map would be

```java
map.put("Dog",2);
```

I know it can be done using `Stream` but I can't find out how.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you want to do is a [*grouping* operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) using the name property as key. That’s the easy part. Trickier is to express “count of distinct colors” as downstream collector. Since there is no such collector in the JRE, we have to built one, utilizing a `Set` storage. Note that even if there was a built-in one, it had to use a similar storage under the hood. So we [*map* the elements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) to colors, [collect them into `Set`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--) (which implies keeping distinct values only) and [finish](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) by querying the size:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = animalStream.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Animal::getName,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.mapping(Animal::getColor, Collectors.toSet()),
            Set::size)));
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = animal.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Animal::getName,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.mapping(Animal::getColor, Collectors.toSet()),
                            Set::size)
                    )
            );
```

Here some test-code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Animal> animal = new ArrayList<>();
    animal.add(new Animal("Dog","black"));
    animal.add(new Animal("Dog","black"));
    animal.add(new Animal("Dog","blue"));
    animal.add(new Animal("Cat","blue"));
    animal.add(new Animal("Cat","white"));

    Map<String, Integer> map = animal.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Animal::getName,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.mapping(Animal::getColor, Collectors.toSet()),
                            Set::size)
                    )
            );

    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry:map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+ " : "+entry.getValue());
    }

}
```

gives

```
Cat : 2
Dog : 2
```

Note: this answer was inspired by this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30282943/1138523

Comment: You could, if you want, use Map::forEach for the test code: map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " : " + value));