# Finding the frequency of distinct combination of strings

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, permutation

I'm trying to find the frequency of distinct combinations of strings in a HashMap. For example, let's say that we have people who have various shopping lists. We will store each shopping list in an ArrayList of type string and map it to a person's name. Then we would have something like the following:

```
 {Megan=[Skim milk, Bananas, eggs, butter], 
  Neal=[Bananas, butter, Whole Milk, Pork Chops], 
  Ash=[Pork Loin, Pork Chops, Skim Milk, butter], 
  Amanda=[Skim milk, strawberries], 
  John=[Whole Milk, eggs, bananas]}.
```

Suppose I store these values in a HashMap called map. So taking the combination of each, this is what I've tried so far:

```
  HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
  // ......
  // Initialize the frequency map ..
  //....

  public void getMostCommon() {
    boolean hasElements;
    for (String person : map.keySet()) {
      Collections.sort(map.get(person));
      ArrayList<String> input = map.get(person);
      //Iterate over each list entry
      for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> listEntry : map.entrySet()) {
        ArrayList<String> tempList = listEntry.getValue();
        ArrayList<String> matchingElem = getMatchingElements(input, tempList);
        hasElements = (temp != null);
        //Count frequency
        if (freq.containsKey(temp)) {
          if (hasElements) {
            freq.put(temp, freq.get(temp)+1);
          }
       } else {
          if (hasElements) {
            freq.put(temp, 1);
          }
        } 
      }
    }
   System.out.println(freq.toString());
  }
```

I use a helper function to check if there are matching elements. Here it is:

```
     public ArrayList<String> getMatchingElements(ArrayList<String> a, 
                                                  ArrayList<String> b) {
       ArrayList<String> retVal = new ArrayList<>();
       if (a.size() >= b.size()) {
         for (int i=0; i < a.size(); i++) {
           for (int j=0; j < b.size(); j++) {
             if (a.get(i).contains(b.get(j))) {
                retVal.add(b.get(j));
                }
               }
             }
          } else {
            for (int i=0; i < b.size(); i++) {
              for (int j=0; j < a.size(); j++) {
                if (b.get(i).contains(a.get(j))) {
                   retVal.add(a.get(j));
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
          return retVal;
         }
```

The problem here is that I do not get the right frequency numbers. I believe it is so because of taking one field static for comparison (the first input) and comparing it with a tempList taken from the entrySet. I think there is double counting here but I do not know how to work around this problem. I want the final output to store the most common count of n items, for all frequencies greater than 0. Something like this would be the frequency of [Skim Milk, Banana], [Eggs, Bananas], etc. How should I go about this problem?

EDIT: Rephrased question/goal.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but my gut fealing would be it could be solved more elegantly with java 8 streams: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282700/java-8-stream-map-and-count-distinct)

Comment: I am trying to get the most common combinations in the list, not the frequency of each list item. I agree that it would look much more elegant with Java 8 streams, however, I am not sure how to use this for counting frequencies of combinations, e.g. [Banana, eggs], [Butter, Skim Milk], etc.

Comment: Given the shopping lists above, what is the complete expected output? Please provide the exact arrays and frequencies expected.

Comment: Let's say we have {Neal=[Water, Apples, Bananas, Milk], Mike=[Apples,Bananas,Granola,Bread], Dan=[Apples, Bananas, Milk], Stacy=[Apples, Bananas, Granola, Water, Milk], Stacy's Mom=[Oranges, Apples, Milk, Water, Granola]}. In this case we could see that the sublist [Apples, Bananas] occurs the most with a frequency of 4, then [Bananas, Milk] with a frequency of 3, etc. I want the combinations inside the lists themselves which are the most frequently occurring.

Comment: I searched for [most common subset](https://www.google.com/search?q=most%20common%20subset) and the results seem to be on the right track, though the math is over my head.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it more complicated then it needs to be. All you need to do is to create another map where you will have a shopping list item as a String key and Integer value that will be the number of times you encountered your shopping list item. At the beginning it will be empty.

Then you go through your original map through each user and iterate through their list. For each item in the list you will check if it is in your new map. If it is not there you will add it as new key and put a value as 1. If it is there then you just need to increase the value by one.

Once you are done you will have a map of your shopping list items mapped to a number of times they were mentioned in the list of all your shoppers.

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
for(String shopper : shppersListMap) {
  List<String> shoppingList = shppersListMap.get(shopper);
  for(String item : shoppingList) {
    if(reasult.containsKey(item)) {
      result.put(item, result.get(item) + 1);
    } else {
      result.put(item, 1);
    }
  }
}
return result;
```

Comment: I understand that would work for each shopping list item. However, I am trying to find the most common occurrence of two or three items which are common in the list. For example, the occurrences of [Skim Milk, Banana] in all shopping lists. I want all the frequencies which are a combination of items. I didn't phrase the question as clear, will edit it now.

Comment: I understood your question just fine. The solution is not for single separate lists. It is to count occurrence frequency of each item in all the lists.

Comment: Are you referring to combinations of items or single items?

Comment: @MichaelGantman, I still doubt. Its probably the frequency of combination of items in all the lists, not each item in all the lists

Comment: Yes, by the end of the algorithm you will have the map that would hold each item as a key and a number of times it was mentioned in all the lists

Comment: @MichaelGantman I don't want each item inside the list counted because I already have that stashed in a separate method. I wanted the highest frequency combinations within the lists themselves. I want to take the frequency of commonly occurring, distinct combinations of items.

Comment: I just added the code to my answer. See if it gives you what you want

Comment: @MichaelGantman this achieves a frequency count for each single item, not the most commonly occurring combination of items.

Comment: Correct. In this case I have to admit I did not understand your question and still don't.

Comment: Fair enough @MichaelGantman, let me try to clairfy. Let's say we have {Neal=[Water, Apples, Bananas, Milk], Mike=[Apples,Bananas,Granola,Bread], Dan=[Apples, Bananas, Milk], Stacy=[Apples, Bananas, Granola, Water, Milk], Stacy's Mom=[Oranges, Apples, Milk, Water, Granola]}. In this case we could see that the sublist [Apples, Bananas] occurs the most with a frequency of 4, then [Bananas, Milk] with a frequency of 3, etc. I want the combinations inside the lists themselves which are the most frequently occuring.

Comment: Ok, I got the question now. I don't have the immediate answer for it. And I am done for the day. I might or might not come back to this next week. Best of luck with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120823/discussion-between-zzzop-and-michael-gantman).