# Java stream collectors in groovy error on Set::size

Tags: java, groovy, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying to do a `SELECT MAX(COUNT DISTINCT field_x) FROM stream GROUP BY field_y;` in a groovy script using Java Streams / Collectors. Basically, I'd like a solution for `COUNT DISTINCT`, that I can then feed into `.max`.

I've been trying the solutions from this post: [java 8 - stream, map and count distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282700/java-8-stream-map-and-count-distinct)

But getting the error:

```
unexpected token: : @ line 65, column 114.
   ")}, Collectors.toSet()), Set::size).val
```

Groovy seems to be having a problem with `Set::size` and `Map::size`.

I've imported both `java.util.Map` and `java.util.Set` to no avail. Is this a problem with Groovy syntax / importing Java classes or a problem with how I'm using `Collectors`? For reference, I've merely tried to implement a forEach println on this map from the original post solution:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = bids.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(
            Bid::getBidderUserId,
            collectingAndThen(
                    mapping(Bid::getAuctionId, toSet()),
                    Set::size)));
```

Apologies if this is more appropriate as a comment, but SO apparently requires more reputation to comment than to ask a question.

Comment: I tried (an approximation of) your code in java and it worked correctly. It seems that you are using `Collectors` correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately groovy does not accepts java method reference syntax, however you can use closures and rewrite it like this

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = bids.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(
            {bid -> bid.bidderUserId},
            collectingAndThen(
                    mapping({bid -> bid.auctionId}, toSet()),
                    {set -> set.size()})));
```

Or (a bit shorter) using closure with [implicit parameter](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#implicit-it) and [method pointer operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#method-pointer-operator)

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = bids.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(
            {it.&getBidderUserId()},
            collectingAndThen(
                    mapping({it.&getAuctionId()}, toSet()),
                    {it.&size()})));
```

***EDIT***

Or even shorter (credits to [@cfrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181392/cfrick)):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = bids.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(
            {it.bidderUserId},
            collectingAndThen(
                    mapping({it.auctionId}, toSet()),
                    {it.size()})));
```

Comment: even shorter: `{bid -> bid.auctionId}` or `{it.&getBidderUserId()}` is just `{it.actionId}`

Comment: @cfrick ahh, you are right! thanks. I'll edit my answer