# Count occurrences by stream

Tags: java, list, collections, stream, hashmap

```
LinkedList<Double> list = new LinkedList<Double>();
list.add(9.5);
list.add(4.9);
list.add(3.2);
list.add(4.9);
```

I want to count the duplicate element in the list through a stream and put them into a `HashMap`  which represent the occurrence of each number in the list:
e.g: (9.5=1, 4.9=2, 3.2=1)
Does anybody know how this works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java 8 - stream, map and count distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282700/java-8-stream-map-and-count-distinct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using `Collections.frequency`**

Make a list of all the distinct values, and for each of them, count their occurrences using the `Collections.frequency` method. Then collect into a `Map`

```
Map<Double, Integer> result = list.stream()
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            v -> Collections.frequency(list, v))
        );
```

**Using `Collectors.groupingBy`**

I think it is not as nice as the example above.

```
Map<Double, Integer> result2 = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity())) // this makes {3.2=[3.2], 9.5=[9.5], 4.9=[4.9, 4.9]}
    .entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> e.getValue().size())
    );
```

**Plain `for loop`**

A plain for loop is quite short, you might not need streams and lambdas

```
Map<Double, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Double d : list)
  map.put(d, map.containsKey(d) ? map.get(d)+1 : 1);
```

**Using `forEach`**

Even shorter with forEach

```
Map<Double, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(d -> map.put(d, map.containsKey(d) ? map.get(d)+1 : 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using `Collectors.counting` which doesn't need the distinct.

```
Map<Double, Long> frequencies = list.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```